# PHP array_shift() not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php

I am creating an array and want to delete the first element of the array and re-index it.  From what I can tell, array_shift() is the right solution.  However, it is not working in my implementation.

I have a member variable of my class that is defined as an array called $waypoint_city.  Here is the variable output prior to shifting the array:

```
print_r($this->waypoint_city);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => JACKSONVILLE [2] => ORLANDO [3] => MONTGOMERY [4] => MEMPHIS )
```

If I do the following, I get the correct result:

```
print_r(array_shift($this->waypoint_city));
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => JACKSONVILLE [1] => ORLANDO [2] => MONTGOMERY [3] => MEMPHIS )
```

However, if I try to reassign the result to the member variable it doesn't work...  Anyone know why that is?

```
$this->waypoint_city = array_shift($this->waypoint_city);
```

If I try to print_r($this->waypoint_city) it looks like nothing is in there.  Thanks to anyone who can save the hair that I haven't pulled out, yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`array_shift`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) changes the array **in-place**. It returns the first element (which is empty in your case):

> Returns the shifted value, or **`NULL`** if *array* is empty or is not an array.

All you have to do is:

```
array_shift($this->waypoint_city);
```

Comment: This is a classic case of RTFM...  I feel like an idiot.  Thanks for setting me straight.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

That's because there IS nothing there. You have element `0` set to nothing, and `array_shift` returns the shifted element, which the first time through is null.

Answer (score 1):

[array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) gets its parameter as reference, so you should call [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) like this:

```
$shiftedElement = array_shift(&$this->waypoint_city);
```